Help with probability problem involving tourist and bear encounters
I am trying to solve the problem below but having a hard time doing it, any help appreciated (my attempt at the bottom). Specifically, I do not know how to solve (b) and I am unsure whether I got other parts right.
Problem: A tourist is walking along a forest path and encounters a bear walking toward him on the same path. When the tourist sees the bear, he steps off the path by a distance described by a random variable $U ∼ U(0,5)$. If the tourist steps off the path by a distance $u$, then with a probability of $\frac{⌈u⌉^2}{30}$​, the bear will continue on its way; otherwise, it will attack the tourist. ($⌈u⌉$ means $u$ rounded up).
(a) What is the probability that the bear will attack?
(b) If we know that the bear did not attack, what is the probability that the tourist stepped off the path by less than 2 meters?
(c) The bear encounters a total of ten tourists during the day. We assume that all encounters follow the same model and are mutually independent. Let $X$ be the number of tourists the bear attacked. Determine $\mathbb{E}(X)$ and $P(X \leq 1)$.
(d) Using the same approach, the bear encounters more and more tourists. Let $T$ denote the index of the tourist (starting from 1) on whom the bear first attacks. Determine $\mathbb{E}(T)$ and $P(T>10)$.
Sketch of my attempt:
(a) Bear attacking follows $Ber(p)$. We can use LOTUS to find an expected value of bear attacks after 1 encounter and thanks to the fact that it should equal to $p$, we get the probability:
$$\mathbb{E}[\frac{⌈u⌉^2}{30}] = \int_0^5 \frac{⌈x⌉^2}{30} f_U(x) dx = \frac{1}{30} \int_0^5 ⌈x⌉^2 \frac{1}{5} dx = \frac{1}{150} \int_0^5 ⌈x⌉^2 = \frac{1}{150} (1+4+9+16+25) = \frac{11}{30} $$
(b) I think we should use a definition of conditional CDF. Let D be the fact (event) that bear did not attack a tourist :
$$ F_{U|D} (2) = P (U \leq 2 | D) = \frac{P(U \leq 2, D)}{P(D)} = \frac{30}{19} P(U \leq 2, D) $$
But I do not know how to calculate it, since $U \leq 2$ and $D$ are not independent.
(c) Use indicators and the linearity of expectation. Let $I_i$ be 1 if i-th tourist was attacked, then $\mathbb{E}(X) = \mathbb{E}(I_1 + ... + I_{10}) = 10(1\frac{11}{30} + 0\frac{19}{30}) = \frac{110}{30}$
(d) Note that $T ∼ Geom(\frac{11}{30})$. Then, $\mathbb{E}(T) = \frac{30}{11}$ and $P(T > 10) = 1 - P(T \leq 10) = 1 - F_T(10) = (1-\frac{11}{30})^{10}$

The definition of $u$ is unnecessarily complicated.  Might as well just take the uniform distribution on ${1,2,3,4,5}$, that way there is no need for the rounding up.  And no need of integrals where a simple  (finite) sum suffices.

Part $b$ is just Bayes' Theorem.  To compute the probability that the bear does not attack, we look at each case ($u\in {1,2,3,4,5}$).  Each case contributes to that probability, some more than others.  The denominator is the probability that the bear does not attack (as you have noted), the numerator is just the terms that correspond to the cases you care about.
